# plotting a bullet-nose curves

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, curve

> I would like to plot this function of Two Variables you can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2COrt.jpg)
>
> $$z^2=t(t-i) \Longleftrightarrow x^2+y^2=4x^2y^2 \Longleftrightarrow y=\dfrac{\pm x}{\sqrt{4x^2-1}}  \mbox{ with } |x|>\frac{1}{2}$$

[image]

would someone show me step by step how to plot this in matlab

is there any script or toolbox in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange
which make plot of that kind of curves quickly

this is by geogebra

[image]

This is by wolframe

[image]

Comment: check this: `syms x y   ezplot('-4*x^2*y^2+x^2+y^2')`

Comment: >> syms x y ezplot('-4*x^2*y^2+x^2+y^2')
Error using sym>convertExpression (line 2068)
Conversion to 'sym' returned the MuPAD error: Error: Unexpected '''.
[line 1, col 1]

Error in sym>convertChar (line 1979)
    s = convertExpression(x);

Error in sym>convertCharWithOption (line 1962)
        s = convertChar(x);

Error in sym>tomupad (line 1693)
        S = convertCharWithOption(x,a);

Error in sym (line 108)
            S.s = tomupad(x,'');

Error in syms>@(x)sym(x) (line 111)
    fvars = cellfun(@(x)sym(x),cvars,'UniformOutput',false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use symbolic variables with `ezplot`.

```
syms x y          % makes symbolic variables
h1 = ezplot('-4*x^2*y^2+x^2+y^2');  % plots the equation
axis equal
set(h1, 'Color', 'k');
```

[image]

Or you can define a function,

```
f = @(x,y) -4.*x.^2.*y.^2+x.^2+y.^2;
h1 = ezplot(f);
set(h1, 'Color', 'k');
```

It won't be easy to have the axis in the middle, I hope it's not necessary to have that.

## Edit

You can download `oaxes` [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30018-oaxes-central-axis-lines-through-an-origin)

```
syms x y 
h1 = ezplot('-4*x^2*y^2+x^2+y^2'); 
axis equal
set(h1, 'Color', 'm');
oaxes('TickLength',[3 3],'Arrow','off','AxisLabelLocation','side',...
    'LineWidth',1)
```

[image]

## Edit

For 3D plot try this,

```
% First line provides a grid of X and Y varying over -5 to 5 with .5 as step-size
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-5:.5:5); 
% instead of "=0", Z takes the values of the equation
Z = -4 .* X.^2 .* Y.^2 + X.^2 + Y.^2; 
surf(X,Y,Z)  % makes a 3D plot of X,Y,Z
```

[image]

You can also try `contourf(X,Y,Z)` for 2D plot.

Comment: could you explain each ligne what does mean and could you make it like wolframe if this possible thanks for ur time

Comment: unfortunately i would like to have  the axis in the middle

Comment: Add the top-level folder, 'customplots', to the MATLAB path. but i ot this message Undefined function 'oaxes' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: copy your script inside `customplots` folder and the call it see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much could you make 3D

Comment: @Educ I add some explanation in the post. Feel free to ask, if you had any problems. Good luck.